# NSLog With NSString And Breaking Up main.m

Tags: objective-c

Before I run this program I have 0 errors or warnings. But when I run it the output I am getting is `(lldb)` and XCode highlights my NSLog output and says `Thread 1 Breakpoint 1`? My first question is why am I not getting any output, and how can I fix what I have to get output? And my second question is how can I break up each one of these parts and put them into their own class. So not have them all in main.m. This is my first day coding in XCode coming from Java so I'm still learning this language. Thank you.

**Part 1**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString * name;
    int age;
    int weight;
}
    /***************************************
     * MUTATORS FOR PERSON INTERFACE
     ***************************************/
    - (void) setName : (NSString *) n;
    - (void) setAge : (int) a;
    - (void) setWeight : (int) w;


    /***************************************
    * MUTATORS FOR PERSON INTERFACE
    ***************************************/
    -(NSString *) getName;
    -(int) getAge;
    - (int) getWeight;
@end
```

**Part 2**

```
@implementation Person
    /***************************************
     * MUTATORS FOR PERSON IMPLEMENTATION
     ***************************************/
    -(void) setName:(NSString *) n
    {
        name = n;
    }
    -(void) setAge:(int) a
    {
        age = a;
    }
    -(void) setWeight:(int)w
    {
        weight = w;
    }



    /**********************************
     * ACCESSORS FOR PERSON IMPLEMENTATION
     **********************************/
    -(NSString *) getName
    {
        return name;
    }
    -(int) getAge
    {
        return age;
    }
    -(int) getWeight
    {
        return weight;
    }
@end
```

**Part 3** This is where I have the problem. It doesen't like NSLog

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Person *p1 = [[Person alloc]init];

        [p1 setName: @"Chris"];
        [p1 setAge:18];
        [p1 setWeight:200];

        NSLog(@"\nName: %@ \nAge: %i \nWeight: %i", p1.getName, p1.getAge, p1.getWeight);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you accidentally added a breakpoint to the `NSLog` line (by clicking on the left margin)? Do you see a blue marker there? Btw, you should not prefix your getters with `get...`, just call them `name`, `age`, `weight`. The `get` prefix is used for something else in Cocoa.

Comment: Yes you are correct there is a blue marker there. I don't know what that means however.

Comment: I got rid of the blue marker and that fixed the problem. What on earth does that thing do?

Comment: It tells the debugger that you want to pause the program at this line. You could then inspect the values of variables etc. There's also a continue button that would allow you to resume execution (in the toolbar of the console output view).

Comment: Unbelievable. I have no idea how you figured that one out thank you! So your also saying that I should leave my set methods like setName but change my get methods to just name? Would that be the correct convention? This learning curve from Java is steeper then I thought!

Comment: That's correct. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) for more details about the naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using NSLog, `%@` is used for logging objects, but those methods return int (a primitive type). Replace them with `%d` (string formatting for Decimal int) and that line should stop crashing.

To split them up, simply create new .m and .h files. XCode should be able to help you with this process. The .m files will automatically be compiled, and .h files should (generally speaking) be included by any file that needs information about the class it refers to. So Part 1 would be Person.h, Part 2 would be Person.h (and include the line `@import Person.h`, and Part 3 would remain in main.m.

Comment: `getName` returns an `NSString`, so `%@` is correct. `%d` is more or less equivalent to `%i`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind me asking, why not just use properties? It will keep your code clean and simple and also saves you a lot of typing.. You should only implement accessors if you need to implement custom behavior a property cannot provide.

Comment: Because I just started yesterday. Trying to get my head around accessors and mutators first b/c that at least looks like java and is something I can relate to. Starting properties today.